# Grails 3.x render dynamic *.gsp template

Tags: grails, render, gsp

Dynamic gsp template is created in my controller, it works well in develop enviroment, but can not work in production enviroment. the code like this:

```
def index() {
    def k = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
    def nowPath = this.class.getResource("/").getPath()
    def controllerName = this.controllerName
    def fileName = "${nowPath}${controllerName}/_${k}.gsp"

    def viewString = new StringWriter()
    def builder = new MarkupBuilder(viewString)
    builder.setDoubleQuotes(true)
    builder.div(id: "create-dataItem", class: "content scaffold-create", role: "main") {
        "g:uploadForm"(controller: "operation4Data", action: "saveDataItem") {
            h1("第${k}次测试")
            h1("test:\${test}")
        }
        def outString = viewString.toString()
        def printer = new File(fileName).newPrintWriter('utf-8')    //写入文件
        printer.println(outString.toString())
        printer.close()

        def test = new Date()
        def view = "${k}"
        render(template: "${view}", model: [test: test, k: k])
    }
}
```

Comment: when developing it works, but deployed it tell cannot find the template.

Comment: You can already dynamically generate content, why do you need to dynamically generate a page that will allow dynamic content?  Can you describe what content you're trying to generate and why it needs to become a dynamic gsp?

Answer (score 0):

In development mode it works, because grails dynamically updates application with your changes (controllers, services, gsps etc.)

I am not sure about your needs, but perhaps yon want just dynamically render the response from controller without template. May be this [part](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews) (Rendering a Response section) of the doc will be helpful

```
render {
   for (b in books) {
      div(id: b.id, b.title)
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem is the code works in ide, but dosn't work when deployed.
In the controller a dynamic template was created, and then render with it.

Comment: What environment is being used, when you run application from IDE? Usually, it is DEVELOPMENT, and the war is being assembled with PRODUCTION env.
The DEVELOPMENT is a special environment, it runs with hot reload option. Grails watching for the updates in the source files and re-load them. I suppose, that is why it works from ide in your case. In production, there is no hot reload, so this approach will not work, or you need to manually update the grails context with the new gsps, emulating hot reload.